# How to proceed when underlying problem solved, but does not match question?

Tags: discussion, questions, question-quality

I have asked this question: [I/O Error on XSane frontend, but not on std out](https://superuser.com/questions/1152274/i-o-error-on-xsane-frontend-but-not-on-std-out)

By now I know what my underlying problem was, but the question was initially on how to get more debugging output.

Should I answer the question? (But my problem with the debugging still stands, I don't know how to get it)

Should I delete the question? (As I don't search for the solution myself by now)

Should I edit it and leave it open?

Currently I edited it to contain the current situation so that anyone reading the question knows the full picture, but the information seems superfluous and it feels like it decreases the quality of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one's answered so, meh, adjust your question, self post an answer.

If someone *had* its probably worth picking the answer closer to what you *asked for* as the correct one, and posting your answer anyway *or* asking a new question and self answering that.